# Take a lower paying job for less stress better culture, no brainer?

Tags: new-job, company-culture, mental-health

I got an offer to do the same work I do now for a private company, but for a public entity. The offer is lower pay, no bonus. But, the schedule will be consistent, no unreasonable deadlines, and all the people are pleasant, no cut throat competition, just a nice environment. Is there any point to staying put, getting higher pay, a big end of year bonus, but enduring a stressful environment? Should I try to change the culture? Or is leaving a no-brainer if the new salary pays the bills and the new environment lowers my blood pressure? The public entity is a client, I've worked with for many years, know all the staff, so it's not a case of 'grass greener on the other side' with respect to culture. Thanks for any advice.

Comment: _"But, the schedule will be consistent, no unreasonable deadlines, and all the people are pleasant, no cut throat competition, just a nice environment."_ How do you know that is really the case? You won't find out how the company culture really is until you've worked there for a while.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can't answer this for you.

Which do you value more, money or happiness? It seems like those are the two choices you're debating.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer, but that’s really the questioners fault for asking a question nobody can answer.